# Error version of cffi python package mismatch

Tags: python, cffi

I'm trying to install a python software (https://github.com/GuLinux/AstroPhoto-Plus) but in  logs, i've got this error during execution just after installation:

```
Exception: Version mismatch: this is the 'cffi' package version 1.14.6, located in '/tmp/pip-build-env-kuxyuc2x/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cffi/api.py'.  
When we import the top-level '_cffi_backend' extension module, we get version 1.14.0, located in '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-38-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so'.  The two versions should be equal; check your installation.
```

As i understand i've got :

```
hamham@astroloutre:~/www$ pip show cffi
Name: cffi
Version: 1.14.0
Summary: Foreign Function Interface for Python calling C code.
Home-page: http://cffi.readthedocs.org
Author: Armin Rigo, Maciej Fijalkowski
Author-email: python-cffi@googlegroups.com
License: MIT
Location: /home/hamham/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: pycparser
Required-by:
```

I'm trying install 1.14.6 version

```
hamham@astroloutre:~/www$ pip install --upgrade cffi==1.14.6
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Processing /home/hamham/.cache/pip/wheels/21/a9/81/c074a48686fe8c1ffada1f9e5f53b553c0f766503c0b991c23/cffi-1.14.6-cp38-cp38-linux_armv7l.whl
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pycparser in /home/hamham/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from cffi==1.14.6) (2.20)
Installing collected packages: cffi
  Attempting uninstall: cffi
    Found existing installation: cffi 1.14.0
    Uninstalling cffi-1.14.0:
      Successfully uninstalled cffi-1.14.0
Successfully installed cffi-1.14.6

hamham@astroloutre:~/www$ pip show cffi
Name: cffi
Version: 1.14.6
Summary: Foreign Function Interface for Python calling C code.
Home-page: http://cffi.readthedocs.org
Author: Armin Rigo, Maciej Fijalkowski
Author-email: python-cffi@googlegroups.com
License: MIT
Location: /home/hamham/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: pycparser
Required-by:
```

Reinstallation and same error :

```
 Exception: Version mismatch: this is the 'cffi' package version 1.14.6, located in '/tmp/pip-build-env-34pknb8l/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cffi/api.py'.  When we import the top-level '_cffi_backend' extension module, we get version 1.14.0, located in '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-38-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so'.  The two versions should be equal; check your installation.
```

I'm not python developper and despite an issue i've posted in github, i've no answer (it seems repository is abandoned sinde one year), i don't know what i can do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resolved with installing package "python3-cffi"

```
sudo apt install python3-cffi
```

and downgrade pip package :

```
pip install --upgrade cffi==1.14.0
```

Comment: this worked for me wth cffi 1.15.x Make a note of whatever version apt is installing, and force pip to use the same.

Comment: error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

Comment: or upgrade it to cffi==1.16.0

Comment: @justdan23 exact,I think my answer is starting to be outdated :)